# Distinguishing words in a sentence

Tags: sql, algorithm

I'm looking for a way to distinguish compound words in a sentence.
Although this is pretty easy in English because there are dashes between words of a compound word (e.g. daughter-in-law), it's not the same in other languages like Persian. In order to detect the words in a sentence we will look for spaces between words. Imagine there isn't a dash to connect these words together, but instead there is a space between them. Fortunately, we already have different records for "daughter" and "daughter in law" in the database. Now I'm looking for an algorithm or SQL query which would first look at bigger chunks of words like "daughter in law" and checks if they exist. If nothing was found, then it should start looking for each word.

Another example would be with digits. Imagine we have a string like "1 2 3 4 5 6". Each digit has a record in the database which corresponds to a value. However, there are extra records for combinations such as "2 3". I want to first get the records for bigger chunks and if there is no record, then check each single digit. Once again, please note that the algorithm must automatically distinguish compounds from singulars.

Comment: It sounds interesting. Can you share your attempts and specify where you got stuck?

Comment: My problem is not the coding, but rather the algorithm with which I can distinguish these words. I've been thinking a lot about different methods, like having a specific table of these special words, and then looking for them, and if anything came up, replace them and then execute a query to find single word (which now have dashes).

Comment: "because there are dashes between words of a compound word" That's not true of all compound words in English.

Comment: I meant mostly. So if it already exists in English, what are the workarounds to find them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For English this problem is solved using full text search binary trees (Huffman Encoding Trees), which take advantage of frequency analysis to put the words/alphabet most used on top of the tree.

[image]

But for Persian implementing such an algorithm is much more difficult because Persian alphabet combines together and it is not discrete like English. So to answer your question about the algorithm, you have to make a Huffman Encoding Tree based on frequency to be able to search against words.

Comment: Thanks. I think that's what I should research. And of course due to such difficulties I will be having more word records in the database. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can build a Directed Acyclic Word Graph (DAWG) from your dictionary. Basically, it's a trie that you can search very quickly. Once built, you can search for words or compound words pretty easily.

To search, you take the first letter of the word and, starting at the root node of the tree, see if there's a transition to that letter. As you match each letter, you get the next letter and see if there's a transition from the current node of the tree for that letter. If you reach the end of the string, then you know that you've found a word.

If you get to a point where there is not a transition from the current node, then:

- if the current node is not marked as the end of a word, then the word you're working with is not a word in the dictionary or a compound word.
- if the current node *is* marked as the end of a word, then you have a potential compound word. You take the next letter and start at the root of the tree.

Note that you probably don't want to implement a DAWG as records in a database.

Comment: Thanks. I'll consider this too. :)